# Checking your site content's Google index ranking

Tags: google-search

Say I use this search in Google, which I know will return a result because I have a page in my site (mysite.com) with that text:

```
wow I like pickles site:mysite.com
```

Is there any way to see what rank my site's page would be in a Google site without using the `site:` search axis, without paging through the list of search results to find my page?

Comment: Or maybe this should go over to webmasters.SE?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search engine optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy!

Use Rank Checker. It even has an extension for Firefox.

http://tools.seobook.com/firefox/rank-checker/

Comment: meh, would rather not sign up for anything...

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). Among the many tools there is a chart of your position in search results for particular search terms.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell, because the search position is different for different people depending on their previous search history.